# Saving a model with PATCH only updates the last-changed property

Tags: backbone.js, model

I'm having a problem persisting disparate model changes at a later time.

When my view catches an update on a field, it triggers an update on the associated model.
Here's some rough psuedo-code:

```javascript
[ snip view boilerplate ]  
"events": {
    "change input": function( event ){
        EventManager.trigger( "field:update", {
            "model": this.model,
            "field": event.target
        });
    },
    "click button": function(){
        EventManager.trigger( "save", { "model": this.model };
    }
}
```

In the event manager:

```javascript
[ snip event manager stuff ]
vent.on( "field:update", function( eventData ){
    var setter = InterfaceClass.getSetterName( eventData.field );

    eventData.model[ setter ]( eventData.field.value );
});

vent.on( "save", function( eventData ){
    eventData.model.save(
        eventData.model.changedAttributes(),
        { "patch": true }
    );
});
```

Unfortunately, `changedAttributes` [only returns the changed attributes since the **last** `.set`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-changedAttributes). This works fine for the workflow of: *update* -> *save* -> *repeat*, but not at all for *update* -> *repeat* -> *save*.

Using...

```javascript
eventData.model.save( null, { "patch": true } );
```

...behaves in essentially the same way, PATCHing only the *last* modified attribute of the model, not all of the changes since the last `.save`.

Now, it's completely possible to circumvent this issue by simply performing a PUT with the entire model instead of a PATCH, but I want to keep my network requests as simple as possible:

```javascript
PATCH {"field": "value", "more": "changes"}
```

is highly preferable in my opinion to

```javascript
PUT {"field": "value", "more": "changes", "other": "same", "thing": "same"}
```

How can I `PATCH` **all** of my model's changed attributes since the last time I saved them?